# Why a div with an empty inline-block has height?

Tags: html, css

```css
div {
 background:red;
}
```

```html
<div><span style="display: inline-block"></span></div>
```

[image: Screenshot]

The w3c send

> On a block container element whose content is composed of inline-level elements, 'line-height' specifies the minimal height of line boxes within the element. The minimum height consists of a minimum height above the baseline and a minimum depth below it, exactly as if each line box starts with a zero-width inline box with the element's font and line height properties. We call that imaginary box a "strut." (The name is inspired by TeX.).

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-box-height

But when the span display is 'inline', why the div's height are 0?

I am confused?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But when the span display is 'inline', why the div's height are 0?

Not 100% correct because if the span has at least one character the height will be different from 0. Even an invisible zero width space:

```css
div {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div><span>​</span></div>
```

In case of an empty span (having `display:inline`) the browser will generate 0 line box. So inside your div there is no line box thus you have a height equal to 0.

Adding one character will trigger the creating of one line box and the rule you quoted will be used and the `line-height` will define the height of the line box and the height of a div is the height of its line box (since we only have one).

Same logic if you add an empty `inline-block` element. Even empty, an inline-block will trigger the creation of a line box.

Same logic if you use an empty `img`:

```css
div {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div><img></div>
```

To use easy words, an `inline-block` element is still considered as an existing element and we need to generate a line box to hold it. An empty inline element will be considered by the browser as a non-existing element so we don't need any line box to hold something that doesn't *really* exist.

> Line boxes are created as needed to hold inline-level content within an inline formatting context. Line boxes that contain no text, no preserved white space, no inline elements with non-zero margins, padding, or borders, and no other in-flow content (such as images, **inline blocks** or inline tables), and do not end with a preserved newline must be treated **as zero-height line boxes** for the purposes of determining the positions of any elements inside of them, **and must be treated as not existing for any other purpose**. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

`line-height` only applies when there are actual lines inside an element, in your case, `<span>`.

Since you did not fill the element with any text, the `div` does not expand.

If you want to leave the span empty, try specifying `height` or adding `margin` to the `span`, like this:

```css
div {
  background: red;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: when the span is 'inline-block' and nothing in it, why the parent div has height?

Comment: This seems to be a result of putting it in the editor. Try it on a regular page, works for me.